# nops_eval giving a error in scan response

Tags: r, r-exams

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I run the following code and get the following error:

```
> ev1 <- nops_eval(
+   register = "RegFile.csv",
+   solutions = "output/metainfo.rds",
+   scans = "nops/choiceresults.zip",
+   string_scans ="nops_string/results.zip"
+ )

The following students were not registered or incorrectly filled in their registration numbers:
6
Correct registration number (for 0000000, POMT2_W23_005.png): xxxxxxx
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 7 did not have 6 elements
```

Any idea how I can figure out which file is producing the error?

The scans seem clean and complete with all the crosses visible.

Comment: Please be very careful when uploading personal documents. The image you have posted is **not** adequately censored, and contains personal data which you are probably not allowed to share. I recommend immediately deleting it and reuploading a properly censored version, and then flagging your own post so that the old image can be permanently deleted by an admin (otherwise it is still visible in the edit history).

Comment: Which part is not censored enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this error occurs it is due to a failed scan and the data in the Daten.txt or the Daten2.txt file.  you just need to rescan the appropriate file and re-run nops_scan.

When you run the scan don't ignore the error lines in the output.  Those errors will prevent the nops_eval from running.

Comment: Yes, indeed, errors during scanning need to be resolved before you can proceed with evaluating the results. Sometimes re-running the scan is enough (as you indicated for your case), sometimes the `Daten.txt` file needs to be fixed manually. If something is still unclear, feel free to follow up.

Comment: I think by now you should be able to accept your own answer by clicking the checkmark on the left of it. Please do so so that the question is marked as resolved here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Sorry, end of semester craziness.  Is there a detailed description of the difference between schoice and mchoice?

Comment: What details are you looking for, what is unclear to you? On the web page there is this overview: https://www.R-exams.org/intro/dynamic/ which also contains a link to a YouTube video about "Single-Choice and Multiple-Choice Quiz". If none of this covers your question, maybe you could ask a separate question here on StackOverflow?